# ReactJS Require Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in reactJS and i can not find why react can not load authorApi using this statement

var AuthorApi = require('../../api/authorApi');

Here is A snips from my project

src/components/authors/author.js code

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var AuthorApi = require('../api/authorApi');

var Authors = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      authors: []
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function () {
    this.setState({ authors: AuthorApi.getAllAuthors() });
  },

  render: function () {
    var createAuthorRow = function (author) {
      return (
        <tr key={author.id}>
          <td>
            <a href={"/#authors/" + author.id}>{author.id}</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            {author.firstName} {author.lastName}
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Authors</h1>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.authors.map(createAuthorRow, this)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Authors;
```

src/api/authorApi.js code

```
"use strict";

//This file is mocking a web API by hitting hard coded data.
var authors = require('./authorData').authors;
var _ = require('lodash');

//This would be performed on the server in a real app. Just stubbing in.
var _generateId = function(author) {
    return author.firstName.toLowerCase() + '-' + author.lastName.toLowerCase();
};

var _clone = function(item) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)); //return cloned copy so that the item is passed by value instead of by reference
};

var AuthorApi = {
    getAllAuthors: function() {
        return _clone(authors);
    },

    getAuthorById: function(id) {
        var author = _.find(authors, {id: id});
        return _clone(author);
    },

    saveAuthor: function(author) {
        //pretend an ajax call to web api is made here
        console.log('Pretend this just saved the author to the DB via AJAX call...');

        if (author.id) {
            var existingAuthorIndex = _.indexOf(authors, _.find(authors, {id: author.id}));
            authors.splice(existingAuthorIndex, 1, author);
        } else {
            //Just simulating creation here.
            //The server would generate ids for new authors in a real app.
            //Cloning so copy returned is passed by value rather than by reference.
            author.id = _generateId(author);
            authors.push(author);
        }

        return _clone(author);
    },

    deleteAuthor: function(id) {
        console.log('Pretend this just deleted the author from the DB via an AJAX call...');
        _.remove(authors, { id: id});
    }
};
```

and here is src/api/authorData.js code

```
module.exports = {
authors:
[
    {
        id: 'cory-house',
        firstName: 'Cory',
        lastName: 'House'
    },
    {
        id: 'scott-allen',
        firstName: 'Scott',
        lastName: 'Allen'
    },
    {
        id: 'dan-wahlin',
        firstName: 'Dan',
        lastName: 'Wahlin'
    }
]
```

};

Error in chrome is :-
  Uncaught TypeError: AuthorApi.getAllAuthors is not a function

Comment: Can u please add directory structure

Comment: directory structure is appearing in author.js picture
thanks for help me

Comment: sorry @radwan didnt check that

Comment: Can you please show the code  of `authorApi` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not exporting your `AuthorApi` function. Try adding:

`module.exports = AuthorApi` at the end of `authorApi.js` file.

Comment: @radwansalah what error you getting after this change

Comment: not sure if this helps, but try changing `this.setState({ authors: AuthorApi.getAllAuthors() });` to `this.setState({ authors: new AuthorApi.getAllAuthors() });` Working example would be great to debug it.

Comment: @Ritchie the same one

Comment: @ioelsonk i am sorry i change the destination before i try you solution
so i roll back and try it again and guess what it is working
thanks

Comment: @ioelsonk module.exports make the AuthorApi global to make react can read it , it that true ?

Comment: It won't make it global object. Read about what global object is in node to have better understanding.

module.exports allows you to use your code in other files = import them. I am really glad I could help. Cheers!